# Flying from Ottawa to Kuwait via London Heathrow

Tags: customs-and-immigration, lhr, british-airways, air-canada

I will be travelling in 3 weeks, going from Ottawa to London Heathrow (LHR), and on to Kuwait.

I arrive at LHR Terminal 2 and, after a 6-hour layover/transit, depart from Terminal 4 for the flight to Kuwait.

1. How do I get from Terminal 2 to Terminal 4 and will I need to go through customs and immigration?
2. Is there a place we can rest whilst not leaving the airport?
3. The entire trip was booked via Air Canada; the first leg is on AC, the second on British Airways. Will I need to claim my baggage from AC, or will it be checked through?

I am flying with a child and I haven't traveled in a while.

Comment: Are you sure its terminal 4? From what I know, BA flights to Kuwait depart from terminal 5.

Comment: I apologize , it is Kuwait Airways that we are going on to Kuwait.

Answer (score 2):

Luckily, Heathrow's website has an [excellent tool](http://www.heathrow.com/flight-connections/personal-connection-planner/AC888/BA157/09-MAR-2017/09-MAR-2017/5/7D) to take the guess work out of this.

I used March 9 as your travel date, flight AC888 from Ottawa and BA157 to Kuwait.

As per the website, you'll have to:

1. Follow the signs for connections.
2. Take the free shuttle bus.
3. Go through security screening.
4. Wait for your next flight.

Its been a long time since I've been through Heathrow so I cannot comment on the rest areas, but from what I know there are individual seating pods and lots of seating areas that you can avail.

You will not need to re-check your bags.